# Swift 5 - Set TextLabel in Custom CollectionviewCell from JSON Array

Tags: ios, json, swift, tableview, collectionview

I have created a custom cell for my collectionview that i have set in a tableview for my app. I need to know to to set the text label to appear as the items in my array that is listed in my JSON File that is local.

View Controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    var workoutData = [Models]()
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        parseJSON()
        
        tableview.register(CollectionTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: CollectionTableViewCell.identifier)
        
        print(workoutData)
    }
    
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return workoutData.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return workoutData[section].title
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return workoutData[section].workouts.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CollectionTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionTableViewCell
        cell.configure(with: workoutData)
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableview.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 250.0
        
    }
    

    
    
    func parseJSON() {
        
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: "json")!
        do{
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            workoutData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Models].self, from: data)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        
        
    }


}
```

My Custom Cell File:

```
import UIKit

class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    var workoutData = [Models]()
    
    

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
    
    static let identifier = "MyCollectionViewCell"
    
    static func nib() -> UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: "MyCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    
    public func configure(with model: Models) {
            self.myLabel.text = //what to put here.
        print(model.title)


    }

}
```

My JSON File:

```
[
        {
            "title": "Chest",
            "workouts": [
                "Bench",
                "Pushup",
                "Incline Press",
                "Decline Press",
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Back",
            "workouts": [
                "Barbell Row",
                "Lat Pulldown",
                "Deadlift",
                "Back Extension",
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Arms",
            "workouts": [
                "Barbell Curl",
                "Dumbbell Curl",
                "Tricep Pressdown",
                "Skull Crusher",
            ]
        }
]
```

I want my text label to show the items in my workouts array. when i set it i get the error "cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String'". I would appreciate any help or directions. Thanks

EDIT:

I am looking to build my layout similar to the horizontal scroll of the the app store

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`workouts` is an array of `String`. So firstly you need to get the String from array by index.

You can use this to show the first value on the label

```
self.myLabel.text = models.workouts[0]
```

Or If you want to show all the `workouts` values on the array then you can use

```
self.myLabel.text = models.workouts.joined(separator: ", ")
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! So what would I need to do to be able to loop through the array so that I could apply each value of the array to the label and it appear as different cells? (I hope that makes sense)

Comment: You want to show all the values on the label for each cell separate by comma or something else?

Comment: @MattyJay94 please check the updated answer.

Comment: I want one value per label per cell. So the first cell would just show bench . And then the next cell would be push up. And so on.

Comment: I see your updated answer but that would list them all on one cell and I need to parse them to different cells if possible.

Comment: is it possible to share any UI that you want to achive?

Comment: I added a picture. I am wanting my app to hold a picture and a label in a horizontal scroll  similar to the app store. That is an old picture but similar to what i am looking to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227865/discussion-between-faysal-ahmed-and-mattyjay94).

Comment: Check this instruction: https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/

Comment: Okay. I will check it out! Thank you!